# Layer animation in UView animation block

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, calayer

Quick question for my curiosity. What effect would animating say a layers position in a animation block have on that layer. I know all about CAAnimations and animating views but in the past I have seen some unexpected results when trying the above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Animating layers would still occur, as UIView sits on the layer of the control, so any animating on the layer would still effect the view.

Comment: What if the layer is backing a uiview. I've seen that changes don't seem to stick when performing the animation on the layer in an animation block. Next time I go to animate the layer I'll get the view jumping around before animating again